# Declare a class of object and use it in the same Class in c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, methods

My problem is that I'm trying to declare the object Node ,declare a vector of objects Nodes and check that vector with a method of the same class, my complier(visual studio 2019) gives me "Error: Unable to open file main.obj. Error code = 0x80070002".

any suggestions to make it work as I described ?

here is my code :

```
class Node {

public:
    int Node_x, Node_y;
    Node(int x,int y){
        Node_x = x;
        Node_y = y;
    }

    bool is_Checked(Node point(int x, int y));
};
vector <Node> visited_Nodes; 
vector <Node> wall_Nodes;
std::vector<Node>::iterator it = visited_Nodes.begin();

bool Node::is_Checked(Node point(int x,int y)) {
    it = std::find(visited_Nodes.begin(), visited_Nodes.end(), point(Node_x, Node_y));
    if (it != visited_Nodes.end()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        visited_Nodes.push_back(point(Node_x, Node_y));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `bool is_Checked(Node point(int x, int y));` supposed to be? That's not how C++ works.

Comment: bool is_Checked(Node point(int x, int y)); is supposed to check is the object (Node) is in the vector of nodes (visited_nodes), if not it adds the node to the visited nodes

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not true that every compiler used in every operating system in the world uses the same exact error codes and messages. Therefore, when asking for help about a compilation error, it is helpful to copy/paste the entire compiler error message, verbatim, as text. This way, even people who don't use the exact same compiler as you do might be able to help you understand what the error message means.

Comment: `bool Node::is_Checked(Node point(int x,int y))` --> `bool Node::is_Checked(Node point)`.

Comment: thank you Sam Varshavchik I re-edit the question

Comment: thank you Jesper Juhl I did what you suggested, but it still giving me the same error

Comment: So, which part of the error message is unclear to you? Your compiler is complaining that it can't create the object file, that much is very obvious. There could only be several things, the configured directory for the object files is wrong, it doesn't exist, or the directory's permissions are wrong, or something along these lines. Check your compiler's configuration and make sure that your compiler can create the object file.

Comment: thanks for your reply Sam Varshavchik, what makes it unclear for me is that the code works just fine without any errors before I add this part to my code, (especially the method and how I use the vector and the iterator in it)

Answer (score 0):

So basically I find out that I can't use find function to find an object in vector of objects (correct me if I'm wrong) so I used elements of the objects (which are unique)

```
  class Node {

    public:
        int Node_x, Node_y;
        Node(int x,int y){
            Node_x = x;
            Node_y = y;
        }

        bool is_Checked(Node point(int x,int y));
    };
    vector <int> visited_Nodes_x;
    vector <int> visited_Nodes_y;
    //vector <Node> wall_Nodes;
    std::vector<int>::iterator it_x = visited_Nodes_x.begin();
    std::vector<int>::iterator it_y = visited_Nodes_x.begin();

   bool Node::is_Checked(Node point(int x,int y)) {
    it_x = find(visited_Nodes_x.begin(), visited_Nodes_x.end(), point(Node_x,Node_y).Node_x);
    it_y = find(visited_Nodes_y.begin(), visited_Nodes_y.end(), point(Node_x,Node_y).Node_y);
    if (visited_Nodes_x.empty() || it_x == visited_Nodes_x.end()) {
        visited_Nodes_x.push_back(point(Node_x,Node_y).Node_x);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```